# How to convert double to object handle to graph a contour plot?

Tags: matlab

I am working with app designer in MATLAB where I have the user input a bunch of parameters and push a button and then generate a contour plot. The app first uses dlmread to save data from 3 separate files to the workspace. Then what the goal is, is to generate a corresponding contour plot on that same GUI that uses data from those 3 files (my x, y, and z parameters).

However, when I run the program, I get an error that says:

```
"Error setting property 'HetroTransSpec' of class 'Parameters':
Cannot convert double value 5 to a handle"
```

`app.HetroTransSpec` is the name of my contour plot. `Parameters` is the name of my GUI application. I will present the code:

```
function SetParametersButtonPushed(app, event)
    spec = dlmread('/Users/******/MATLAB/SphoHetroTest/Spec3.txt'); %Load spec file
    assignin('base', 'spec', spec);
    pop=dlmread('/Users/******/MATLAB/SphoHetroTest/pop.txt');
    assignin('base', 'pop', pop);
    lambda=dlmread('/Users/******/MATLAB/SphoHetroTest/lambda.txt'); %read wavelenght axis (nm)
    assignin('base', 'lambda', lambda);
```

Now, here is my code to take these parameters (spec, pop, lambda) to generate my contour plot. Except I am getting that error:

```
app.HetroTransSpec = contourf(pop,lambda,spec);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a contour plot is not a handle, but contour data, as opposed to some other plotting functions.

Try:

```
[~,handle]= contourf(pop,lambda,spec);
app.HetroTransSpec =handle;
```

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but what am I supposed to do for [~,handle]?

Comment: @P_Drach do for? in Your question, you need to give to `app.HetroTransSpec` a handle, as the error says. While most plotting functions (e.g. `plot`, `surf`) return a handle, so you can do `app.HetroTransSpec =surf(...)`, `contour` returns a matrix with the contours (of type `double`, see the error?) as first output, a handle a second. The code I showed ignores (`~`) the first output, catches the second one and gives it to `app.HetroTransSpec`